# Disturbed by the Sanctum mechanic

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

When I need to do a front and back which speaks to each other with APIs, I do like this:

- the user connects with their login/password
- the back checks and if it is good returns a token to the front
- the front stores this token in the localStorage
- and for all future requests, the token is added in the form of Bearer
- and for each request, the back checks the presence/validity of this token (middleware)

Perfect. Everything works.

Except that I read that storing the token in localStorage is not secure at all. And that it is better to use cookies. And this is precisely what Sanctum allows with Laravel. If I understand correctly, with Laravel Sanctum no more need for a token, everything happens with cookies between front and back. This is what I see with my different tests. I understood well?

I am disturbed by this.

Comment: Yes, you understood well. So what’s disturbing about it? Cookies in Laravel are encrypted. Opaque tokens you save to localStorage are not. Storing plaintext tokens in the user’s browser is far more disturbing to me personally.

Comment: I am (was) disturbed because I store the token in local storage for years. And I just understood that I was wrong. I have to rethink everything that I thought was correct. Thanks for your answer Martin.

Comment: Everything is correct as far as it goes. perhaps one small addition. The token is nothing more than the csrf token that is fetched from the frontend to the backend via an api call and stored as a cookie. this means that the apiroutes and the webroutes can be encrypted. The cookie storage location is perfectly fine.